# Error using Sonos Acme Service for first time

Tags: sonos

I have setup the Sonos Acme Services on an AWS instance. When I goto test the service website I get "Error activating Acme Service on Sonos"

I have the service setup remotely running on an AWS instance. I've gone to Sonos and opened all the ports the devices may required just in case.

The output log when launching the server shows

```
Starting Application on [ip].us-east-2.compute.internal 
with PID 24660 (/home/centos/contentapi-sample-app/build/classes/main started by centos in 
/home/centos/contentapi-sample-app)
```

I also came across this in the log but the default binding should exist

```
2019-06-24 00:16:50.686  WARN 24660 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] 
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             
: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] 
in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

It should show a default launch message. I'm wondering if it's due to the server binding to the AWS internal IP address instead of the external one.

Comment: I couldn't submit an edit because it needs to be 6 chars long, but the content in the code fences can't go on the same line as the triple backticks. Add a newline after the opening ``` on each.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like the default homepage message is actually an error with the end points being listed out in a different document. Not the best programming logic or should have given a notice of such but meh

Answer (score 0):

The error message received on the root path / is normal as the web routes do not contain any roots. If you watch the logs in the server startup it lists all the routes you can test.